# How can I create a subscriptable class from existing classes

Tags: python, class, object

I am trying to bundle multiple classes together to create a new object which is subscriptable to each layer. The idea is to define `n` layers from a number of predefined `x` classes for the new class, and each layer can be addressed from within the object. Not dissimilar from layers of a cake. Example code is:
'''

```
class Frosting(object):
  def __init__(self, Size, flavor):
    self.Size = Size
    self.flavor = flavor

class Bread(object)
  def __init__(self, Size, flavor)
    self.Size = Size
    self.flavor = flavor

class Filling(object)
  def __init__(self, Size, flavor)
    self.Size = Size
    self.flavor = flavor
```

How can I approach a new class so that I can put the layers of the new cake together so that I can figure out what the cake layers are afterwards? I have been trying to build a Cake Layer list and can put that into another list but the new list is not subscriptable. My current approach is:

```
layer0 = Bread(10, 'Vanilla')
layer1 = Frosting(5, 'Chocolate') 

newCake = [layer0, layer1]
```

and I want to build a class so that instead I can use it like the following:

```
CakeFoo = BuildCake(newCake)
```

where:

```
print(CakeFoo.Frosting.flavor)
```

prints out `Chocolate`

Currently I need to do `CakeFoo[1].Type` to find 'Chocolate', which works but is not what I want for future needs. Ideally the method/class would take `newCake` and create new layers for each of the objects in the list.

What can I be doing to make this work?

Comment: It's not really clear why `CakeFoo[1].Type` isn't sufficient. What do you want to write instead?

Comment: My cake can have anywhere from 5 - 10 layers or more, and I want to keep all of the layers together in a single object so that I can save it to a DB and then pull the data when it needs to be used later.  Each layer type will have a unique processing, so being able to subscript the layers is important for making sure the correct functions are used with the data.

Comment: That object would be a list. Again, what is wrong with `for layer in CakeFoo: t = layer.Type; ...`?

Comment: `print(CakeFoo.Frosting.flavor)` doesn't seem like a great API. What if a cake has *two* kinds of filling? Plus, tying the API to the class names inhibits refactoring - changing your class structure gets very awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This achieves what you want. I've refactored things a little bit.

It should be fairly self explanatory. In `Cake.__init__` you just iterate through the layers attaching attributes to `self`:

```py
class Layer:
    def __init__(self, size, flavor):
        self.size = size
        self.flavor = flavor


class Frosting(Layer):
    ...


class Bread(Layer):
    ...


class Filling(Layer):
    ...


class Cake:
    def __init__(self, layers):
        for layer in layers:
            setattr(self, type(layer).__name__, layer)


cake = Cake([Frosting(10, "chocolate"), Bread(4, "apple"), Filling(3, "spam")])
print(cake.Frosting.flavor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code and adapt it if necessary:

```
class CakeFoo(object):
    pass

layer0 = Bread(10, 'Vanilla')
layer1 = Frosting(5, 'Chocolate')
layer2 = Filling(20, 'Cream')

CakeFoo.Bread = layer0
CakeFoo.Frosting = layer1
CakeFoo.Filling = layer2

print(CakeFoo.Bread.flavor)
print(CakeFoo.Frosting.flavor)
print(CakeFoo.Filling.flavor)

print("---------------------------")
# to access to the layer in the order set by the list
newCake = [layer0, layer1, layer2]

for layer in newCake:
    layer_in_CakeFoo = getattr(CakeFoo, layer.__class__.__name__)
    print(layer_in_CakeFoo.flavor)
```

The output of its execution is:

```
Vanilla
Chocolate
Cream
---------------------------
Vanilla
Chocolate
Cream
```

Comment: This is how I would build a class if I knew there were only two layers. Can you help me understand how to do this for n layers? In this case newCake is n long? If a for loop would do this, I am going to feel dumb.

Comment: @Robert Simpson I have changed the answer adding the list that I have missed in the previous answer. CakeFoo contains all the layer and by `getattr(CakeFoo, layer.__class__.__name__)` you can get a reference to a layer object in the order established by the list `newCake`